# JAVA/JXL- Different colors for the text in a cell

Tags: jxl

I would like to set part of the text in a cell to one color(font color) and other part to another color. Is this possible with jxl api ? or it is a limitation?

example:

i have 'name*' in cell, now i want the color of 'name' in blue and '*' in red.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that. please check the following code.

```
     WritableFont TableFormat = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 8, WritableFont.BOLD,false, UnderlineStyle.NO_UNDERLINE, Colour.WHITE);
     WritableCellFormat tableFormatBackground = new WritableCellFormat(); //table cell format
     tableFormatBackground.setBackground(Colour.DARK_BLUE) ; //Table background
     tableFormatBackground.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN,Colour.BLACK); //table border style
     tableFormatBackground.setFont(TableFormat); //set the font
     tableFormatBackground.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTRE);// set alignment left
```

Comment: Your code does not answer the question. He want different color in one cell not different color on background and text....

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and looks like a copy from other article that doesn't have to do with the question asked (table alignment???)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible.
Same as you I was looking for this solution as well as how to use regular and bold fonts in the same cell (like: "version: 1.2.3.**4**"), but as much as I saw, jxl doesn't support different format in the same cell... :(